# Product Projection Search with Facets details alone. Need to avoid result array

Tags: commercetools

Is there any way when I am searching products for one category just for facets alone. In this call I want to avoid result array Example :

```
{
    "limit": 20,
    "offset": 0,
    "count": 20,
    "total": 24,
    "results": [],
     "facets":{
 "variants.attributes.productStyle.en-GB": {
                    }
}
```

There can be 20 products, but I need only facets results alone to avoid huge data coming to service. If there is any query It would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for getting no products returned set the `limit` parameter to `0` in your API request.